# Is there a word in English for a man who leaves his pregnant wife and child?

Tags: single-word-requests

In Season 1, Episode 2 of the British show *Peaky Blinders*, Polly tells her pregnant niece Ada:

> The longer you leave it, the worse it gets. Believe me - I know. I was
>   16. And I didn't dare tell anyone... In the end, I did it myself. I did it
>   to myself. And I almost died. And he didn't come back. They don't. Why
>   should they? You know the words. You're a "whore". The baby's a "bastard". **But there's no word for the man who doesn't come back.**

Is the emboldened sentence in the quote above true?

**Is there really no word in English for a man who leaves his pregnant other half and child?**

Comment: At least in America, we call him a *douche*. Or sometimes a variation such as *douche bag* or just *DB* for short.

Comment: "Deadbeat husband" is a common term.  Terms like *douche* or *asshole* can apply to any jerk.

Comment: If such a word exists in your native language, please post it along with its meaning,  and maybe this will trigger someone's memory. I *really* don't think there is a noun which means a husband who abandons his wife and children. There are many suitable single-word insults (see Hot Licks' comment) but  you're not looking for that, are you?

Comment: Thanks for asking, @Tonepoet. I was looking specifically for a word, as that's the premise posed by the quote in question - I wanted to ascertain how true it was.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A - My native language is English; I wasn't comparing differences between languages, simply trying to determine just how true the quote from the TV show was.

Comment: "Man who doesn't come back" is very different from "husband who abandons his pregnant wife and/or child"; which are you talking about?

Comment: I was talking about a "man who doesn't come back". I didn't really imply a marriage in my question, but I've commonly heard "deadbeat" in contexts where a couple are simply *together*, regardless of whether they're married, so I feel it's a good fit regardless.

Comment: @Tonepoet ..... his pregnant girlfriend, his pregnant wife what difference does it make? Is there going to be a different noun that describes this chap because he married one but not the other? **Hashim**, your username lead me to surmise your were a non native speaker. I hope my earlier comment didn't offend you.

Comment: Good point, I'd forgotten that I mentioned wife, but I didn't mean to be so specific. None taken, @Mari-LouA.

Comment: Edited to remove "wife" to make it less specific. I also removed the term "agent noun" for the same reason - I don't see why the question needs to ask for a specific type of word, especially since as the highest-voted answer isn't an agent noun and that the question doesn't inherently require one. The question as it now stands seems as clear and unambiguous as it can be made, and I feel like any further editing would be death by pedantry.

Comment: Please [edit] this to add a sample sentence as required by the question tag.

Comment: Perhaps I'm perverse, but the question is not clear to me. For example, although he eventually returned, Odysseus was for a long time a man who left his wife and child; hence, "odyssean husband" would suit as an answer. Thus, and given that the point of view is not specified, it seems incumbent upon the question to stipulate that a perjorative is desired. Other examples from literature bear out my point; it is not always cadish, but rather sometimes heroic, to leave your "pregnant other half and child". How the act is viewed depends on circumstances, which are not stipulated in the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use ***deadbeat husband***, borrowing from ***deadbeat dad*** — [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/deadbeat-dad)

> (noun) 1. A father who neglects his responsibilities as a parent, esp. one who does not pay child support to his estranged wife.

You will definitely find many examples for [*deadbeat husband*](https://google.com/#q=%22deadbeat+husband%22) on Google.

Comment: I know of no single-word for this. So this should be a useful term instead.

Comment: I can't find the part in the question where it specifies the man is married to the woman... is it implied somewhere? My assumption after reading it was that they weren't, based on the word "bastard."

Comment: Deadbeat dad is more common. I mean, if there's no kid involved, the guy is just a jerk..

Comment: @sumelic - There's nothing in the *quote*, but the OP decided that the man was leaving his wife in his question, which would mean they were married. So basically the question isn't fully supported by the quote that inspired it.

Comment: Selected as current best answer because **deadbeat** seems the closest word English has for this specific scenario, so the quote seems to make a poignant point; the closest word that exists is still not as vitriolic nor specific as either "whore" or "bastard".

Comment: Deadbeat dads can still live with their partners and kids. It refers to their lack of care, not abandonment.

Comment: Yes  but the question does not hint that its main interest is shirking financial responsibilities...

Answer (score 6):

He is a ***cad and a bounder***.  These are British English terms, and were very insulting in their day, if spoken by one gentleman to another. They were often used together:

> You are a cad, sir, and a bounder, to treat your wife so!

*cad*,  [Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/cad)

> a man who behaves badly or dishonestly, especially to women:
>
> He's a cad and a bounder - I'm not in the least surprised he let you
>   down

The reference says this is British English.  I don't know if it is used much nowadays, and it doesn't seem strong enough to me.

*bounder*, [Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/bounder)

> a man who behaves badly or in a way that is not moral, especially in
>   his relationships with women.

Answer (score 3):

Do you need it to be a single word?  If so:

> [abandoner](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/abandoner): a person or thing that abandons (Collins)

Example: He hadn't set out to be an abandoner.  But when he found himself still incarcerated when the due date came, he became profoundly depressed at the role he was forced to play.

Answer (score 2):

Though not very common in this context,  ***runaway*** should still work.

ODO:

> **[runaway](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/runaway)**
>
> *NOUN*
>
> **1** A person who has run away, especially from their family or an institution.
>
> ‘How ironic that in this family, the runaway in question is a parent,
>   not some rebellious teenager.’